# Insert rows automatically

Tags: c#, sql

I have 3 tables:

**Table 1**

`CustomerID  Name    Sname    Zipcode
 1           test1   test1    xxx2
 2           test2   test2    yyy2
 3           test3   test3    xxx2`

**Table 2**

`StaffID   Name   sname
 1         Jack   Mack
 2         Jhon   Addison`

**Table 3**

`ID   CustomerID   StaffID
 1    1            1`

I am not sure if SQL can do this, So in C# what I want is if StaffID 2 is not in Table 3 and if a staff wants to visit all the customers in zipcode xx2 then by click on a visit button he should be inserted for all the zipcode. So if I select Zipcode xxx2 then the query should first check if I am not visiting same Zipcode for a specific, if not then add the person into table 3 so the updated table 3 will look something like this:

`ID   CustomerID   StaffID
 1    1            1
 2    1            2
 3    3            2`

As you can see, StaffID 2 would like to visit xxx2 zipcode as a result he gets 2 entries into Table 3 because there are two CustomerID with Zipcode same as xxx2.

I have did some online research I would this `IF EXISTS (SELECT` but it just add one entry. Also I guess I will be expecting 3 parameter from C# zipcode, CustomerID and StaffID

Comment: Does table 3 need to persist or do you need a query that would give table 3 as the result but it never gets stored in the database? Also I think I understand what you want but I don't get the "*if StaffID 2 is not in Table 3*" requirement.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Table 3 is there so it will check the zipcode from table1 and insert the results into table3. Table3 has FK from StaffID (table3) to StaffID(table 2) and Customer (table3) to CustomerID (table1) So if StaffID2 is already visiting CustomerID 2 then its no point having another entry for him in Table3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description it appears you just need a simple insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (CustomerID, StaffID)
select CustomerID, @StaffId from Table1
where Zipcode = @zipcode
    and NOT EXISTS(select StaffID from Table3 where StaffID = @staffId)
```

Comment: do i require INSERT INTO Table3 (CustomerID, StaffID) values (@CustomerID, @SaffID) because that would be supplied from user C#. And will this automatically add the StaffID to all the zip code?

Comment: No, you use this instead of that call. a INSERT INTO can either use `values` and add one row of information or you can chain it in to a `select` statement like I did.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql query, assuming you are passing @StaffId, @CustomerId and @Zip as parameter

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (CustomerID, StaffID)
SELECT CustomerID, @StaffId FROM Table1
WHERE Zipcode = @zip
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT StaffID FROM Table3 WHERE StaffID = @staffId 
AND CustomerID = @CustomerId)
```